# Read xml from NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, macos, ios

I create `NSURLConnection` to send an request like

```
"http://www.mysiteabc.com/api.php?email=emailtologin@gmail.com&password=123321"
```

and recives an xml like

```
<response>
TOKEN=abcdef
</response>
```

in `NSData`. Anybody can tell me how to read TOKEN from `NSData` return by `NSConection`.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone OS has no (good) native support for XML (since `NSXMLParser` is way to limited).
You should use an opensource XML-parser (based on `libxml2`) like TouchXML (http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML).
There're actually many topics on StackOverflow about parsing xml-data and there're lots of tutorials out there so it probably won't be too hard to implement it in your application.